# How do I get the value of an input in a table, relative to clicked button

Tags: jquery

At the moment I have a table setup with buttons and inputs, and I am trying to get the value of the input, relative to the button I pressed. i.e. if I press button 1, Input 1 and its value is requested, and if I press button 2, input 2 is request, etc.

I have removed the inputs from the table, and had them one after another, and they reference the correct inputs, and display the correct values. I did so with the "next" function. However, once within the table structure they display "undefined".

I tried changing to "closest", trying to implement a class, but all return "undefined".

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).next('input').val()); //should i be using a different function?
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button>Alert 1</button></td>
    <td><input type='text'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button>Alert 2</button></td>
    <td><input type='text'></td>
  </tr>
</table>`<br> this is what the Jquery looks like<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button and the input are not in the same level (they're not siblings), instead of `$(this).next('input').val()` you may use `$(this).parent().next('td').find('input').val()` which finds the `input` in the next `td`.

```js
$("button").on('click', function() {
  alert(
    $(this) /** the clicked button **/
    .parent() /** the "td" where the button is placed **/
    .next('td') /** its next "td" **/
    .find('input') /** the input field **/
    .val() /** the input's value **/
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button>Alert 1</button></td>
    <td><input type='text'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button>Alert 2</button></td>
    <td><input type='text'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT :**

Thanks to [David Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82548/david-thomas), a more feature-proof way to do the task is to use `closest` method to find the nearest `tr` and from it get the `input`, also adding a `class` to these `input`s is more robust than selecting them using the tag name (as the markup can be changed anytime).

```js
$("button").on('click', function() {
  alert(
    $(this) /** the clicked button **/
    .closest('tr') /** the nearest "tr" (next) **/
    .find('input.txt-field') /** the input field **/
    .val() /** the input's value **/
  );
});
```

```html
<!-- the inputs now have the same class-name -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button>Alert 1</button></td>
    <td><input type='text' class="txt-field"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button>Alert 2</button></td>
    <td><input type='text' class="txt-field"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a really clear explanation of what the next function is doing.

Comment: @DamianMorris you're welcome ! Glad I managed to provide some help.